# How to data bind to the CSS top, left, width, and height of a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

I'm trying to use KnockoutJS to build an interactive dashboard with data bindings on different aspects of the `style` property; namely `left`, `top`, `width`, and `height`. For example, I'm using JQuery UI along with ui-draggable and ui-resizable effects to enable users to drag panels around on a canvas and resize them however they see fit. Without KnockoutJS, I was simply iterating over each div and stealing these properties from the dom element. I'm sure there's a better way using KnockoutJS, right?

To explain my problem a little better, consider two panels side by side:

```html
<div id='dashboard'> 
  <div id='panel1' class='ui-draggable ui-resizable' data-bind='?????'> 
    <!-- content goes here -->
  </div> 
  <div id='panel2' class='ui-draggable ui-resizable' data-bind='?????'> 
    <!-- content goes here --> 
  </div> 
  <button data-bind='click: send'>Update</button> 
</div>
```

My view model looks something like this (note: pseudo coded for brevity):

```
var viewModel = { 
  panels: [ 
   { id: 'panel1', left: 0, top: 0, width: 50; height: 50 }, 
   { id: 'panel2', left: 50, top: 0, width: 50; height: 50 } ], 
  send: function() { 
   ko.utils.postJson( location.href , { panels: this.panels } ); 
  } 
}; 
ko.applyBindings( '#dashboard', viewModel );
```

I'd like to bind it in such a way that when the user sizes any of the div elements (ie. the panels), that it would then update the underlying viewModel using the built in data binding `OnMouseUp`. Then when the user clicks the "Update" button, I would then post the coordinates to the server.

I'm thinking it might have something to do with custom templates, but even there I ran into some complexities that I couldn't quite grasp in managing the mouse events on each panel.

```html
<script type='text/html' id='panelTemplate'>
    <div class='ui-draggable ui-resizable' 
         style='top: ${ top }; left: ${ left }; width: ${ width }px; height: ${ height }px;'>
        <!-- content goes here -->
    </div>
</script>
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having exactly the same problem: bind a KnockoutJS model to collection of draggable and resizable divs. The solution is to use custom binding and handle the event of end of resize and end of drag, as I explain [here](http://mkramar.blogspot.com/2011/06/jqueryui-draggable-and-resizable-with.html).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnSave').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Save.ashx',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: ko.toJSON(viewModel),
                    error: function () { alert("ajax error"); }
                });
            });

            ko.bindingHandlers.jqDraggableResizable = {
                init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
                    var obj = valueAccessor();
                    var $elem = $(element);

                    element.dataObj = obj;

                    $elem.resizable({
                        stop: function (event, ui) {
                            this.dataObj.H(ui.size.height);
                            this.dataObj.W(ui.size.width);
                        }
                    });

                    $elem.draggable({
                        stop: function (event, ui) {
                            this.dataObj.X(ui.position.left);
                            this.dataObj.Y(ui.position.top);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        });
```

Answer (score 5):

With time passing the way that it does I was not able to see Green's solution in JSFiddle and the solution from Awais seemed a little long so I slugged through it some more.

I found the following binding works for setting the width. The parens and the 'px' seem to be important. In my case 'AWidth' is the width of a div tag.

```
data-bind="style: {width: AWidth() + 'px'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was answered over on the [KnockoutJS Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/knockoutjs/browse_thread/thread/1e149514022a7ae6#) by a brilliant developer named Green.

He demonstrated how to do this using a custom extension library (that he built) for KnockoutJS. His solution allow additional JQueryUI events to be "bindable" (ie. drag & resize). He then posted his solution along with his knockout-ext.js file out on JSFiddle for me to use and learn from it.

**Thanks again, Green**! :)

Comment: Green is brilliant indeed, and knockout rocks!

Comment: I've had to revisit this issue and see that this approach is no longer supported. I've looked at Awais Qami's solution above and it appears to work well. While Green's solution was brilliant, I am now accepting Awais' post as my accepted answer (since I'm now using it). :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working with a simple solution, it builds off Ryans view.

This allows me to save my changes real time as I drag drop elements, with BreezeJS

in viewmodel

```
ko.bindingHandlers.draggable = {
    init: bindDraggable
};

function bindDraggable(element, value) {
    $(element).draggable({
        stop: onStopDrag
    });

    function onStopDrag(event, ui) {
        ko.dataFor(element).PositionX(ui.position.left);
        ko.dataFor(element).PositionY(ui.position.top);
        datacontext.saveChanges(); //if you want real time updating on drop
    }
}
```

and in my view

```
<div data-bind="foreach: posts">
<div class="BoardPost" data-bind="style: { top: PositionY() + 'px', left: PositionX() + 'px' }, draggable:null">
    <div class="Title" data-bind="text: Content"></div>
</div>
```